# Issues with saving referenced objects with mongoose

Tags: node.js, reference, mongoose

This is my song schema. *ignoring import statements*

```
var SongSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    genre: String,
    artist: String,
    album: String,
    year: Number,
    composer: String,
    lyrics: String,
    duration: Number // [seconds]
});

var Song = module.exports = mongoose.model('Song', SongSchema);
```

This is my playlist schema

```
var PlaylistSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    genre: String,
    songs: [{
        details: {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'Song'
        },
        upvote_count: Number,
        state: String,
        type: String
    }]
});

var Playlist = mongoose.model("Playlist", PlaylistSchema);
```

faulty code:

```
console.log("object:", song.details);
var newSong = new Song(song.details);
newSong.save();
console.log("song:", newSong);
newPlaylist.songs.push({
    details: newSong._id,
    upvote_count: song.upvote_count || 0,
    state: song.state || SongState.QUEUED,
    type: song.type || SongType.NOT_FROZEN
});
```

on saving this playlist using the above code I get the following error,

```
object: { name: 'String',
genre: 'String',
artist: 'String',
album: 'String',
year: 2010,
composer: 'String',
lyrics: 'String' }
song: strictMode=true, selected=undefined, shardval=undefined, saveError=undefined, validationError=undefined, adhocPaths=undefined, removing=undefined, inserting=undefined, version=undefined, , _id=undefined, populate=undefined, populated=undefined, wasPopulated=false, scope=undefined, _id=default, duration=modify, lyrics=modify, composer=modify, year=modify, album=modify, artist=modify, genre=modify, name=modify, , _id=true, , duration=true, lyrics=true, composer=true, year=true, album=true, artist=true, genre=true, name=true, , stateNames=[require, modify, init, default, ignore], ownerDocument=undefined, fullPath=undefined, domain=null, , _maxListeners=0, isNew=true, errors=undefined, _bsontype=ObjectID, id=VSriÆùá÷%ß8, duration=42, lyrics=, composer=, year=2015, album=, artist=, genre=, name=, $__original_save=function () {
  var self = this
    , hookArgs // arguments eventually passed to the hook - are mutable
    , lastArg = arguments[arguments.length-1]
    , pres = this._pres[name]
    , posts = this._posts[name]
    , _total = pres.length
    , _current = -1
    , _asyncsLeft = proto[name].numAsyncPres
    , _asyncsDone = function(err) {
        if (err) {
          return handleError(err);
        }
        --_asyncsLeft || _done.apply(self, hookArgs);
      }
    , handleError = function(err) {
        if ('function' == typeof lastArg)
          return lastArg(err);
        if (errorCb) return errorCb.call(self, err);
        throw err;
      }
    , _next = function () {
        if (arguments[0] instanceof Error) {
          return handleError(arguments[0]);
        }
        var _args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)
          , currPre
          , preArgs;
        if (_args.length && !(arguments[0] == null && typeof lastArg === 'function'))
          hookArgs = _args;
        if (++_current < _total) {
          currPre = pres[_current]
          if (currPre.isAsync && currPre.length < 2)
            throw new Error("Your pre must have next and done arguments -- e.g., function (next, done, ...)");
          if (currPre.length < 1)
            throw new Error("Your pre must have a next argument -- e.g., function (next, ...)");
          preArgs = (currPre.isAsync
                      ? [once(_next), once(_asyncsDone)]
                      : [once(_next)]).concat(hookArgs);
          return currPre.apply(self, preArgs);
        } else if (!_asyncsLeft) {
          return _done.apply(self, hookArgs);
        }
      }
    , _done = function () {
        var args_ = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)
          , ret, total_, current_, next_, done_, postArgs;

        if (_current === _total) {

          next_ = function () {
            if (arguments[0] instanceof Error) {
              return handleError(arguments[0]);
            }
            var args_ = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1)
              , currPost
              , postArgs;
            if (args_.length) hookArgs = args_;
            if (++current_ < total_) {
              currPost = posts[current_]
              if (currPost.length < 1)
                throw new Error("Your post must have a next argument -- e.g., function (next, ...)");
              postArgs = [once(next_)].concat(hookArgs);
              return currPost.apply(self, postArgs);
            } else if (typeof lastArg === 'function'){
              // All post handlers are done, call original callback function
              return lastArg.apply(self, arguments);
            }
          };

          // We are assuming that if the last argument provided to the wrapped function is a function, it was expecting
          // a callback.  We trap that callback and wait to call it until all post handlers have finished.
          if(typeof lastArg === 'function'){
            args_[args_.length - 1] = once(next_);
          }

          total_ = posts.length;
          current_ = -1;
          ret = fn.apply(self, args_); // Execute wrapped function, post handlers come afterward

          if (total_ && typeof lastArg !== 'function') return next_();  // no callback provided, execute next_() manually
          return ret;
        }
      };

  return _next.apply(this, arguments);
}, save=function wrappedPointCut() {
  var args = [].slice.call(arguments);
  var lastArg = args.pop();
  var fn;

  return new Promise.ES6(function(resolve, reject) {
    if (lastArg && typeof lastArg !== 'function') {
      args.push(lastArg);
    } else {
      fn = lastArg;
    }
    args.push(function(error, result) {
      if (error) {
        self.$__handleReject(error);
        fn && fn(error);
        reject(error);
        return;
      }

      fn && fn.apply(null, [null].concat(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1)));
      resolve(result);
    });

    self[newName].apply(self, args);
  });
}, $__original_save=[function (next, options) {
  // Nested docs have their own presave
  if (this.ownerDocument) {
    return next();
  }

  var hasValidateBeforeSaveOption = options &&
    (typeof options === 'object') &&
    ('validateBeforeSave' in options);

  var shouldValidate;
  if (hasValidateBeforeSaveOption) {
    shouldValidate = !!options.validateBeforeSave;
  } else {
    shouldValidate = this.schema.options.validateBeforeSave;
  }

  // Validate
  if (shouldValidate) {
    // HACK: use $__original_validate to avoid promises so bluebird doesn't
    // complain
    if (this.$__original_validate) {
      this.$__original_validate({ __noPromise: true }, function(error) {
        next(error);
      });
    } else {
      this.validate({ __noPromise: true }, function(error) {
        next(error);
      });
    }
  } else {
    next();
  }
}, function (next, done) {
  var Promise = PromiseProvider.get(),
      subdocs = this.$__getAllSubdocs();

  if (!subdocs.length || this.$__preSavingFromParent) {
    done();
    next();
    return;
  }

  new Promise.ES6(function(resolve, reject) {
    async.each(subdocs, function(subdoc, cb) {
      subdoc.$__preSavingFromParent = true;
      subdoc.save(function(err) {
        cb(err);
      });
    }, function(error) {
      for (var i = 0; i < subdocs.length; ++i) {
        delete subdocs[i].$__preSavingFromParent;
      }
      if (error) {
        reject(error);
        return;
      }
      resolve();
    });
  }).then(function() {
    next();
    done();
  }, done);
}], $__original_save=[]
CastError: Cast to string failed for value "[object Object]" at path "songs"
at MongooseError.CastError (/media/D/codebin/grep/node_modules/mongoose/lib/error/cast.js:19:11)
at SchemaString.cast (/media/D/codebin/grep/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schema/string.js:434:9)
at Array.MongooseArray.mixin._cast (/media/D/codebin/grep/node_modules/mongoose/lib/types/array.js:124:32)
at Array.MongooseArray.mixin._mapCast (/media/D/codebin/grep/node_modules/mongoose/lib/types/array.js:295:17)
at Object.map (native)
at Array.MongooseArray.mixin.push (/media/D/codebin/grep/node_modules/mongoose/lib/types/array.js:308:25)
...
```

As you see, the newSong that I save, has a value of a function. Can someone please point me where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Your PlaylistSchema is incorrect. Take a close look at the 'songs' array - you have a `type` field, so mongoose interprets the schema as saying "songs is an array of Strings." Rename the `type` field to something like `kind` or set a [custom `typeKey`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#typeKey) and it should work.

Comment: thanks @vkarpvov but I don't understand how Playlist's schema would affect the saving of a Song. My guess is that the object returned is a promise, but the documentation says it should be the saved object.